# How to force a browser to show the latest changes to a CSS file?

Tags: php, css, caching

I made some changes on a CSS file on a PHP site.

The changes do not show up in any browser I test it on until I hold down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and click the browser's <kbd>REFRESH</kbd> button.

This means that most users are not going to seem the changes I made.

**How can I force browsers to show the changes to CSS files immediately (without renaming the CSS file)?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add a unique string as query string when linking the stylesheet.  Here's an example

```
<link href="style.css?<?=filemtime("style.css")?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your web server. Apache can be set to configure the maximum cache time for a given file, and I'm pretty sure IIS can do the same.

Alternatively, a common solution to FORCE uncaching is to version your CSS file names ([Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) does this internally). For example, `style.css` becomes `style-10162009.css`

Answer (score -1):

You can't.

If the new CSS file has the same name as the old the browser will use the cached file. This means that you've either got to:

1. use some form of `css_filename.css?version_number`
2. or, use another name for the new file
3. or, do as you're doing, and use ctrl+F5

Comment: The cache will eventually update to the new file just not straightaway.

Comment: Well, yes; but I was presuming the necessity of its doing so *immediately* rather than at *eventually*. =)