# Website doesn't apply CSS when locally hosted with XAMPP

Tags: html, css

On my .php file I just started to write the website. So I started by linking the .css files. But they don't work. I plan to use php in this file so I use the PHP exetension and run it with the latest version of XAMPP

By taking a look in the network tab, I see that the .css files are there with status 200.

```css
body {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="mainheader">Kraut und Rueben</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Full code here: https://github.com/AlexBrightwater/Kraut_und_Rueben/tree/main/frontend
Using JS fiddle, I can confirm that the code theoretically works. https://jsfiddle.net/1vfn6Ly0/

I saw posts here from some years ago but their solutions didn't work:

- [How to force a browser to show the latest changes to a CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581040/how-to-force-a-browser-to-show-the-latest-changes-to-a-css-file)
- [XAMPP Server does not load CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502863/xampp-server-does-not-load-css-files)
- [Chrome - Disable cache for localhost only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751767/chrome-disable-cache-for-localhost-only)

Comment: If the files are being loaded with a 200 this implies they are being applied successfully. If they aren't adjusting the appearance of your HTML in the way you'd expected then that needs fixing separately - we would need to see examples of the CSS you're trying to apply, and the HTML you're trying to apply it to, and what changes you were expecting to see from the application of those rules. In other words, please provide us a [mre] of your issue. See also [ask] for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. Something you could do to verify more easily if it's your environment which is at fault, or the combination of HTML and CSS not working together, is to run the code in another environment. With HTML/CSS this is quite easy - you can just paste the code into a site like JSFiddle or CodePen and run it there, and see what result you get. There's even a "code snippet" feature within Stackoverflow which can be used for this purpose too (you can find it when you edit your question).

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How is this related to PHP?

Comment: Added code to example @ADyson

Comment: Thanks. I made it into a runnable snippet as you can see (you don't need the JSFiddle now). So as you've seen yourself, the CSS is trivial and works ok. If you're not seeing it working in your local environment, but yet the CSS files are returning 200 OK when loaded into the page, then it's a bit mystifying. When you are looking at the network tab for those CSS files, can you look in the raw Response tab for each of the files and confirm whether they actually contain the CSS you're expecting them to (and no other stuff which might make it invalid)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you see the request to the CSS file being successful in your Network tab, we can infer that a file with such a name has successfully loaded (but please double-check that the name is exactly what you think it is).

Look now into the file that has been loaded in the Sources tab and see whether your rule is there indeed. If so, then navigate to the elements tab and see whether such a rule is being applied to the `body`. It may be the case that such a rule exists though, but it's deactivated due to a conflicting other rule, which has higher priority. In this case you will see where the other rule comes from and you should have no trouble fixing this discrepancy from here on.

But, if the file downloaded does not contain the rule you expect, then possible reasons include:

- server cache
- browser cache
- wrong file (maybe a file by the same name was loaded from a different place)

Therefore empty your caches and figure out where the file is being loaded from.

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar issue, and I was able to solve it with a simple solution.

I changed the appropriate file permissions to read and write. I had to do this for each folder and file. I have this problem if I copy over files from another location, but not if I create files directly in the htdocs folder.

Comment: If that was the problem then the response would be 403 and not 200.